# Returning A BOOL from a Class Function defaults to NO.

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, parse-platform, block

I'm currently trying to set up my Parse app for moderators but i'm hitting a lot of road blocks.

One is i'm having a hard time finding literature concerning blocks/pointers to educate myself. So my first request would be if anyone is knowledgable in these areas direct me to some good online resources for reading up on these topics. Secondly my issue lies in a class function, where class is GlobalFunctions, which is a subclass of NSObject.

Class function is the following:

```
+(BOOL)userIsModerator {

if ([PFUser currentUser]) {
    PFQuery *queryRole = [PFRole query];
    [queryRole whereKey:@"name" equalTo:@"Moderator"];
    [queryRole getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
        PFRole *role = (PFRole *)object;
        PFRelation *moderatorRelation = [role users];
        PFQuery *queryModerators = [moderatorRelation query];
        [queryModerators whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser].objectId];
        [queryModerators getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *moderatorObject, NSError *error) {
            if (!error && [moderatorObject.objectId isEqualToString:[PFUser currentUser].objectId]) {
                // Current user belongs to the Moderator role.

                return YES;
            } else {

                return NO;
            }
        }];
    }];
}    
}
```

That alone throws warnings my way stating :

> Incompatible block pointer types sending 'BOOL'(^)(PFObject *_strong, NSError*__string)' to paramater of (PFObject* __nullable __strong, NSError* __nullable __strong)

So I thought I could circumvent that by incorporating a BOOL inside the class function:

```
+(BOOL)userIsModerator {
__block BOOL isModerator;

if ([PFUser currentUser]) {
    PFQuery *queryRole = [PFRole query];
    [queryRole whereKey:@"name" equalTo:@"Moderator"];
    [queryRole getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
        PFRole *role = (PFRole *)object;
        PFRelation *moderatorRelation = [role users];
        PFQuery *queryModerators = [moderatorRelation query];
        [queryModerators whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser].objectId];
        [queryModerators getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *moderatorObject, NSError *error) {
            if (!error && [moderatorObject.objectId isEqualToString:[PFUser currentUser].objectId]) {
                // Current user belongs to the Moderator role.

                isModerator = YES;
            } else {

                isModerator = NO;
            }
        }];
    }];
}

if (isModerator) {
     NSLog(@"logged in user is moderator");
    return YES;
} else {
    NSLog(@"logged in user is not moderator");
    return NO;
}

}
```

This rides the function from any warnings but always returns NO, even if my currentUser is a moderator

Comment: I don't agree this is the same question. It has nothing to do with threads, but everything to do with blocks. Even if I put the result on the main thread the BOOL still defaults to NO because of a block issue, or perhaps because it's a class function, i already tried updating it on the main thread prior to posting the question

Comment: It is the same. In your code, you are doing a background (asynchronous) request for the data. Meanwhile, your `userIsModerator` method returns long before that request is even started.

Comment: @rmaddy I do agree with that because I can log it succesfully in the `getFirstObject` block but in `if(isAdmin)` it will always be NO. So its returning before the request started, so how do I resolve this? As I stated before I already tried putting it on the main thread prior to posting the question

Comment: See something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632780/method-bool-return-from-inside-block

Comment: Has nothing to do with the fact that it's a class method. You simply can't get a result from the Block _until the Block runs_.

Comment: Okay thank you @rmaddy i'll give her a try

Comment: @JoshCaswell that's what I figured, just didn't know how to ask it right, should have included more of 'what i have tried' in my question. putting it on the main thread is always my go to with Parse result blocks

Comment: Your code sees the query request and creates a separate thread to run that, then moves on with the rest of the code immediately, even though the other thread hasn't run yet.  So you start a thread, then check the bool, then the thread runs and properly sets the bool.  You will have to create a listener outside of the block, and trigger that listener from inside of the block when you set the bool.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I decided just to use another completion `block :(void(^)(BOOL isModerator))completion` and set it as a void method instead.